# How to create for each point feature an Euclidian Distance raster in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, shapefile, modelbuilder, distance

I need some comment on how to create an Euclidian distance raster for a point dataset of about 100 features in ArcGIS. I need to create a raster for each single point.
My question is, if there is a tool that allows me to interpolate the already existing Eucledian distance ratser to each single point OR if I need to create a Model Builder to cue it.
In the picture you see an example. The green feature are points.

[image: Euclidian distance for a single point]

Comment: why do you need so many euclidian distance raster ? It is possible with a loop but I am afraid that this will be overkilling.

Comment: this raster is the baseline information to perform a fuzzy viewshed

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions do exist such as copying the raster and adjusting the cell values based on the x,y difference of the next point (virtually not actually). Your points are not equally spaced or merely going in a cardinal direction so I think a system that manipulates the current single raster to get to your end results is achievable but will be quite complex.

At only 100 points and a simple Euclidean distance function I would just batch the process and the use the required cell statistics.